# Can android clear files from the cache directory of my application while it is running?

Tags: android, caching

I am implementing an image file cache in my application to reduce the number of times these files are downloaded directly from the web server. While I know the Android OS may decide to clear files from the cache directory of my application to free up internal storage space, I'm not quite sure if this "cleanup" process can happen even during its execution.
If I could assume the OS won't mess with the cached files during execution, I would be able to use "in memory" data structures to optimize my cache implementation. For example, I could use a map (in memory) of cached entries (files stored on the cache folder) containing time stamps of cache hits and other information that might be useful to prioritize the way cached entries are recycled. Otherwise, if I have to deal with the fact that the cache cleanup process may happen anytime, anywhere, even during app execution, use of in memory data structures would be useless because they would eventually become out of sync with the real contents of the folder in the event of the OS deciding to clean up files by itself. In which case my cache system would have to be less efficient because it would be forced to keep checking the contents of the cache folder directly in the file system everytime a new file is requested by the app.
In other words, I just want to know if I can assume the contents of the cache directory wont be changed by the OS concurrently with my app because that might considerably change my cache implementation.

Comment: Shabbir, my question is different. I know how to create and delete files on my app's cache directory and exactly when I should do it. I just want to know if I can assume that while my app is running it will be the only one messing with the cache contents. Or, in other words, when Android decides to clear cache files to recover internal storage space, does it preserve cache folders of running apps?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Two answers, neither have anything to do with the question. 

Answer (score 0):

just delete all files from the cache directory with normal method

```
public void clear() {
    File[] directory = getCacheDir().listFiles();
    if(directory != null){
        for (File file : directory ){
            file.delete();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Clearing the cache directory is not the problem. I just want to know if I can assume the contents of the cache directory wont be changed by the OS concurrently with my app.

Answer (score 0):

While the application is running, you may allocate new objects and that will remain on the RAM and not been paged out, so you must release the memory from your app by releasing the object references making the memory available to the garbage collector, but if there is any file without modification, the system may paged it out of the RAM if it wants to use that memory elsewhere. So it'll be a better approach to handle memory management on your side and not reside on system. You can do the following:

```
Set<SoftReference<Bitmap>> mReusableBitmaps = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

LruCacheString mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, BitmapDrawable>(mCacheParams.memCacheSize) {

    @Override
    protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, String key,
            BitmapDrawable oldValue, BitmapDrawable newValue) {
        if (RecyclingBitmapDrawable.class.isInstance(oldValue)) {
            ((RecyclingBitmapDrawable) oldValue).setIsCached(false);
        } else {
            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                mReusableBitmaps.add
                        (new SoftReference<Bitmap>(oldValue.getBitmap()));
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are sure that now these bitmaps no longer used you can remove them as follows:

```
if (mReusableBitmaps != null && !mReusableBitmaps.isEmpty()) {
        synchronized (mReusableBitmaps) {
            final Iterator<SoftReference<Bitmap>> iterator
                    = mReusableBitmaps.iterator();
            Bitmap item;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = iterator.next().get();

                if (null != item && item.isMutable()) {
                    if (canUseForInBitmap(item, options)) {
                        bitmap = item;

                        iterator.remove();
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also go for the [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), this will manage all your bitmap caching

Comment: My idea was to use the the local fs, or more precisely, my app's cache directory to cache downloaded JPG files. It surely wouldn't be as fast as caching (expanded) bitmaps in memory, like you suggested, but would have the advantage of saving a lot more RAM because entries would be kept compressed (as JPEG files) and stored in the fs. I just wanted to know if I had to worry about the possibility of Android concurrently changing the contents of the cache folder. But anyway I've been testing Picasso, as you suggested and it might be exactly what I need here.  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: As far as your application is on the screen you have the control to manage the cache, unless the system is running out of memory. If you have ever tested your app on low end devices e.g having RAM of around 512MB and you have a grid of around 6 bitmaps, if you haven't optimized your bitmap, then your app will crash there itself saying out of memory.